# Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Tags: c#

I have this code in web forms:

```
namespace TrendsTwitterati
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<TweetEntity> tweetEntity = tt.GetTweetEntity(1, "")
                .DistinctBy(e => e.EntityPicURL);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(
            this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
        {
            HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
            foreach (TSource element in source)
            {
                if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                {
                    yield return element;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this code I get the error

> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class.

My question is

1. I cannot change this partial class to static. How will I accomplish the same without it?

Comment: Create separate static class with `DistinctBy` method in it.

Comment: Judging by the brace layout it would seem that your extension method isn't really in any class at all. So it's just a matter of putting it in its own static class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add new `static` class and define your extension methods inside it. Check out [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb383977.aspx) for Extension methods.

```
 namespace TrendsTwitterati 
 {
    public partial class Default: System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    }

    public static class MyExtensions 
    {
        public static IEnumerable < TSource > DistinctBy < TSource, TKey > (this IEnumerable < TSource > source, Func < TSource, TKey > keySelector) 
        {
            HashSet < TKey > seenKeys = new HashSet < TKey > ();
            foreach(TSource element in source) 
            {
                if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                {
                    yield
                    return element;
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Nice trick with the inner static class, but I had no idea what I was looking at at first with the spaces between the angle brackets and the types.

Answer (score 3):

Add your method into `static` class for extension method in this way

```
namespace TrendsTwitterati
{
    public static class Extension
    {
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
          (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
          {
               HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
               foreach (TSource element in source)
               {
                   if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                   {
                       yield return element;
                   }
               }
          }  
     }
}
```

Now use it

```
namespace TrendsTwitterati
{
     public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
          protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
               List<TweetEntity> tweetEntity = tt.GetTweetEntity(1, "").DistinctBy(e => e.EntityPicURL);
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: How will I call this from page_load function?

Comment: @Venkat: You just call it like any other instance method on the type you're extending. You do have to reference the namespace where the `Extension` class resides, but you never have to reference `Extension` itself.

Comment: got it . Now i get an error this way.  Error 13 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TwitterHandlerCore.TweetEntity>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<TwitterHandlerCore.TweetEntity>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Venkat add `.ToList()` after  `.DistinctBy()`